# Como tratar calendário no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, calendar

Olá,

Estou fazendo um projeto pessoal, para praticar programação e me deparei com uma situação que estou com dificuldades para resolver. Um usuário tem uma rotina que se repete semanalmente, onde cada dia da semana ele tem tempo livre diferente, por exemplo:

Segunda-feira ele tem de 17 às 20h livre, já terça-feira tem das 8 às 14h, e assim vai até domingo, mas na próxima segunda ele tem o mesmo horário livre, das 17 às 20h livre.

Qual é o melhor método de guardar esses horários de tempo livre em um banco de dados `MySQL`. De forma a ser eficiente e ocupar o menor espaço possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabela: **HorariosLivre**

```
id*   |usuario_id  |  dow   |   hora_inicial   |   hora_final
 1         1           2             17                20
 2         1           3             08                14
```

onde, `usuario_id` é fk para tabela de `usuarios`, e `dow` é o 'day of week' ou seja, dia da semana, sendo domingo = 1, e sábado = 7.

veja mais sobre a função do mysql, `DayOfWeek()`:http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php